# Improve my Python Turtle game to make it more compact

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm a beginner in programming and I started making a game using Python Turtle. The game works fine but I feel like it has a lot of unnecesary code and I want to make it more compact. Can someone give me some advice on making it more efficient?

In this game there are 3 turtles: red green and blue. You pick one of them (blue is picked by clicking b, green by clicking g and red by clicking r) and if your turtle places first, you win 1 point, if second you don't get any points, but if you place third you lose one point. You can restart the game by pressing h. The score is saved in a file named "database.txt".

```
import turtle
import random
import time

global score

file = open('database.txt','r+')

score = file.read()

playing = True

global n
n = 0

turtle.setup(500, 400)

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Gamble on Turtles")

screen = turtle.Screen()

global x1
x1 = 0
global x2
x2 = 0
global x3
x3 = 0

def red_turtle():
    global turtle1
    turtle1 = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle1.shape("turtle")
    turtle1.color("red")
    turtle1.penup()
    turtle1.setpos(-180, 100)
    turtle1.pendown()

def green_turtle():
    global turtle2
    turtle2 = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle2.shape("turtle")
    turtle2.color("green")
    turtle2.penup()
    turtle2.setpos(-180, 0)
    turtle2.pendown()

def blue_turtle():
    global turtle3
    turtle3 = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle3.shape("turtle")
    turtle3.color("blue")
    turtle3.penup()
    turtle3.setpos(-180, -100)
    turtle3.pendown()

def track():
    i = 30
    track = turtle.Turtle()
    track.hideturtle()
    track.speed(100)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(-150, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.right(90)
    track.write(i)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(-120, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*2)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(-90, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*3)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(-60, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*4)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(-30, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*5)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(0, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*6)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(30, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*7)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(60, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*8)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(90, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*9)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(120, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*10)
    track.forward(300)

    track.penup()
    track.setpos(150, 150)
    track.pendown()
    track.write(i*11)
    track.forward(300)

def bet_red():
    global n
    global x1
    global x2
    global x3
    global score

    message = turtle.Turtle()
    message.hideturtle()
    message.penup()
    message.forward(180)

    n = 3
    move()
    if n == 3:
        keys_deactivate()
        if x1 > x2 and x1 > x3:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            score = int(score) + 1
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('+1 point')
            file.close()

        elif x1 > x3 and x1 < x2 or x1 < x3 and x1 > x2:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('+0 point')
            file.close()
        else:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            score = int(score) - 1
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('-1 point')
            file.close()

def bet_green():
    global n
    global x1
    global x2
    global x3
    global score

    message = turtle.Turtle()
    message.hideturtle()
    message.penup()
    message.forward(180)

    n = 3
    move()
    if n == 3:
        keys_deactivate()
        if x2 > x1 and x2 > x3:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            score = int(score) + 1
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('+1 point')
            file.close()

        elif x2 > x1 and x2 < x3 or x2 < x1 and x2 > x3:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('+0 point')
            file.close()
        else:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            score = int(score) - 1
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('-1 point')
            file.close()

def bet_blue():
    global n
    global x1
    global x2
    global x3
    global score

    message = turtle.Turtle()
    message.hideturtle()
    message.penup()
    message.forward(180)

    n = 3
    move()
    if n == 3:
        keys_deactivate()
        if x3 > x1 and x3 > x2:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            score = int(score) + 1
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('+1 point')
            file.close()

        elif x3 > x1 and x3 < x2 or x3 < x1 and x3 > x2:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('+0 point')
            file.close()
        else:
            file = open('database.txt','r+')
            score = int(score) - 1
            file.write(str(score))
            message.write(score)
            message.left(90)
            message.forward(20)
            message.write('-1 point')
            file.close()


def gamble():
    global screen
    screen.onkey(bet_red, "r")
    screen.onkey(bet_green, "g")
    screen.onkey(bet_blue, "b")
    screen.listen()

def keys_deactivate():
    screen.onkey(None, "r")
    screen.onkey(None, "g")
    screen.onkey(None, "b")

def move():
    global x1
    global x2
    global x3

    x1 = random.randint(30, 330)
    x2 = random.randint(30, 330)
    x3 = random.randint(30, 330)

    global turtle1
    global turtle2
    global turtle3

    turtle1.forward(x1)
    turtle2.forward(x2)
    turtle3.forward(x3)

def restart():
    global screen
    screen.clear()
    game()

def game():
    red_turtle()
    green_turtle()
    blue_turtle()
    track()
    gamble()
    global screen
    screen.onkey(restart, 'h')

game()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: If your code works please post to Code Review

Comment: Look into classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a rework of your code that tosses 60% of it.  With a complete rethink, it could probably be smaller:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

FONT = ('Arial', 16, 'normal')
STARTING_LINE = -180

def make_turtle(color, y_offset):
    turtle = Turtle("turtle")
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(STARTING_LINE, y_offset)
    turtle.pendown()

    return turtle

def track():
    track = Turtle(visible=False)
    track.speed('fastest')
    track.right(90)

    for i in range(30, 360, 30):
        track.penup()
        track.setpos(STARTING_LINE + i, 150)
        track.pendown()
        track.write(i)
        track.forward(300)

def bet_red():
    keys_deactivate()
    move()
    bet_race(turtles['red'].xcor(), turtles['green'].xcor(), turtles['blue'].xcor())

def bet_green():
    keys_deactivate()
    move()
    bet_race(turtles['green'].xcor(), turtles['blue'].xcor(), turtles['red'].xcor())

def bet_blue():
    keys_deactivate()
    move()
    bet_race(turtles['blue'].xcor(), turtles['red'].xcor(), turtles['green'].xcor())

def bet_race(x1, x2, x3):
    global score

    if x1 > x2 and x1 > x3:
        score += 1

        message.write(score, font=FONT)
        message.left(90)
        message.forward(20)
        message.write('+1 point', font=FONT)

    elif x1 < x2 and x1 < x3:
        score -= 1

        message.write(score, font=FONT)
        message.left(90)
        message.forward(20)
        message.write('-1 point', font=FONT)

    else:
        message.write(score, font=FONT)
        message.left(90)
        message.forward(20)
        message.write('+0 point', font=FONT)

    with open('database.txt', 'w') as file:
        print(score, file=file)

def gamble():
    screen.onkey(bet_red, "r")
    screen.onkey(bet_green, "g")
    screen.onkey(bet_blue, "b")

def keys_deactivate():
    screen.onkey(None, "r")
    screen.onkey(None, "g")
    screen.onkey(None, "b")

def move():
    for turtle in turtles.values():
        turtle.forward(randint(30, 330))

def restart():
    message.clear()
    message.home()
    message.forward(180)

    for turtle in turtles.values():
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setx(STARTING_LINE)
        turtle.pendown()

    gamble()

score = 0

try:
    with open('database.txt') as file:
        score = int(file.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 400)
screen.title("Gamble on Turtles")

turtles = {
    'red': make_turtle('red', 100),
    'green': make_turtle('green', 0),
    'blue': make_turtle('blue', -100)
}

message = Turtle(visible=False)
message.speed('fastest')
message.penup()
message.forward(180)

track()

gamble()

screen.onkey(restart, 'h')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Key things to note:

- You don't understand `global`, take some time to (re)read about it. 
  Your code uses 32 `global` statements, the rework only has *one*.
- Similarly, you should rethink your management of global entities and
  avoid creating so many.  A key concept to keep in mind while
  programming this would be, *"How hard would it be to add one more
  turtle to the race?"*.  If it would be difficult, you need to rethink
  your code.
- You can't assume that `database.txt` exists when you first run the
  code -- program accordingly.
- Turtles as a resource are not garbage collected so avoid creating
  more than you need.  Currently you create five new turtles every time
  the race is rerun.  The reworked code reuses the same turtles over
  again and avoids redrawing the track.
- Amazingly, your code is devoid of loops and data structures.  If you
  want compact and efficient code, you'll want to learn about these.

Comment: cdlane, can you suggest me a good source to learn python?